Embedded Python packages not recognised by Intellisense (Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.10.1)
I am creating a Unity project that has python embedded using this tutorial, here. For some reason Inillisense is warning that the installed packages, which used pip, were not reconised. I have made sure that my custom Python environment is properly set up, as Visual Studio is reconising the correct installed packages.
Visual Studio reconising installed packages
Visual Studio version: Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.10.1
Python version: 3.12.3
What I have done:

I've added lib and site-packages to _pth
I've changed the Python environmnet path to point to both lib and site-packages in Visual Studio
Made sure that I have my custom Python Environment selected

What I was expecting:
All of these trys was to get the installed python packages to be reconised

Here is a similar ticket about python intellisense issue. Please check it to see if it helps.

@DouXu-MSFT I've taken a look at the link and the suggestions haven't worked, a lot of the information is old and does not apply to the 2022 version of Visual Studio, but thanks anyway

Hi @Oliver White, i followed  the tutorial you shared to try to reproduce the issue in VS2022, but i can't use pip in embedded python3.12. When i create a script to use python and open in vs, it shows like this.It seems that intellisense works normally.

Hi @DouXu-MSFT, intellisense works on the C# side just fine, it's the Python side that is the issue. If you want to get pip working in the embedded version, this comment, helped getting pip to work. After some testing though since the post, I have concluded that it's a bug with intellisense, as ignoring the problem and implementing an example code from one of the installed packages, it worked fine; minus some issues with Unity and Python.

Hi @Oliver White, i am able to get pip to work following your comment link. I installed Numpy for test and could not see the intellisense warning. Could you share a screenshot to show me that installed packages were not reconised?

Hi @DouXu-MSFT, this is what is happening Image. Also installed packages are recognised, Visual Studio is showing them in the python environment.

I can reproduce the same issue by following your steps on Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.10.1. I have found some other users have reported the same issue on here.
As AdamYoblick and bschnurr said:

Please refer to the linked issue for any updates. This is in our backlog to fix, but we have other tasks with higher priority unfortunately.


vs 2022 Preview 4 will have a fix when its released

I think what can be done at the moment is waiting for the issue to be fixed. As a workaround: Try to  close the solution in VS and re-open it to see if the issue persists.
Hope it can help you.
